# Manually passing this onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to manually pass "this" value from a different function

jQuery

```
$('#divName ul li a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$(window).scroll(function() {
    //for condition a
    //the value of this will a

    //for condition b
    //the value of this will be
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var elem = '';
$('#divName ul li a').on('click',function(e){
     $(this).addClass('active');
     elem = $(this);
     alert(elem);
    e.preventDefault();
});


$(window).scroll(function(){

  // Use the elem variable here
    console.log('The Variable this is recently cliked element : '+ elem)   
 //for condition a
 //the value of this will a

//for condition b
 //the value of this will be
});​
```

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/bebVt/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to implement click and scroll functionality? Put the scroll handler *inside* the click handler.

```
$("div").click(function(e) {
    var target = this;
    $(window).on("scroll.clickScroll", function(e) {
        // Use "target" as the reference to what was clicked on.
    }
}
```

Note that you will have to remove the handler when the click stops like so:

```
$(window).off("scroll.clickScroll");
```

I have used event name spacing here to differentiate a normal window scroll and your specialised click scroll.